# Rotate div-element inside another

Tags: html, css, rotation, rotatetransform

I prepared a Fiddle for you to show what my problem is:

I need to turn some text placed inside of a div-tag so that it appears vertically.
No problem so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/pSDLY/

HTML:

```
<div class="board">
  <div class="boardheading">
     <div class="verticalText">AVeryLongLongLongLongWord</div>
  </div>
  <div class="boardelement">
      Some larger content here<br>
      Some larger content here<br>
      Some larger content here<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

relevant CSS:

```
div .boardheading {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: visible;
    background: blue;
    /*See here: I want to have a fixed width and an automatically calculated height*/
    width: 20px;
}

div .verticalText {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

But as you can see, the height of the div doesn't adjust to his content. Neither does the width. I want the width to be as small as possible (20px should be an appropriate size for me, but setting the width doesn't have any effect as you might see in the fiddle)

Any ideas on how to reach this?

Answer (score 0):

This should start you in the right direction.

```
div .verticalText {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background: blue;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: mmh, no. this isn't what I want to reach. I need the whole row adjusting to the given height then and the width of the first column still needs to be smaller.